# difference in ORDER BY in SQL vs SQLite

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, order

У меня есть два запроса

для SQLite

```
SELECT TableName FROM tbl 
WHERE Status = 2 ORDER BY TableName

> BuildingStages 
> Buildings
```

и такой же для MySQL

```
SELECT TableName FROM tbl gl 
WHERE Status = 2 ORDER BY gl.TableName

> Buildings 
> BuildingStages
```

но я получаю записи в разном порядке.
Как это исправить?

Comment: Язык перепутан, или сайт.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по результату, первая сортировка сделана с учётом регистра, а вторая - без.

Можно попробовать [сделать так](//stackoverflow.com/a/5958065/4928642):

```
SELECT TableName FROM tbl ORDER BY TableName COLLATE NOCASE ASC
```